# Translate bools to bit sequence

Tags: c++, boolean, byte, bit

Looking for some operator (I'm guessing in place of + ?) that will do

```
unsigned char bits = true + false + true + true + true;  // 1 byte is sufficient
```

to become to following bit pattern:

```
00010111
```

Then how can I check that bit pattern in an if

```
if (bits == 00010111)
```

Comment: `BOOST_BINARY` for the second question.

Answer (score 6):

you want

```
bits = true << 5 | false << 4 | true << 3 | true << 2 | true << 1;
```

or

```
bits |= true;
bits <<= 1;
bits |= false;
bits <<= 1;
bits |= true;
bits <<= 1;
bits |= true;
bits <<= 1;
bits |= true;
```

Comment: `+` works in place of `|`, if for some reason he prefers that syntax.

Comment: Instead of + you could also use ^ . The issue with both is that they are not invariant if applied twice. That is true << 1 | true << 1 is different from true << 1 + true << 1 which is different from true << 1 ^ true << 1. Only true << 1 == true << 1 | true << 1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)'s string constructor.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string bits;
    bits.push_back('1');
    bits.push_back('0');
    bits.push_back('1');
    bits.push_back('1');
    bits.push_back('1');
    std::bitset<8> bitset(bits);
    std::cout << bitset.to_string();

}
```

There are better ways of doing this though.

Comment: Ah yeah but he used the addition operator and I can't exactly mimic that except by pushing back. I thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/). There is a method to set various bits and to convert to a unsigned long. Just do an `&` operator on that to get the byte.

Answer (score 2):

The operator + would need to do a shift left by one bit of the current value, then "bitwise OR" the incoming true or false and return that.

This is a quickie implementation I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
    int result;

public:
    Foo() : result(0) {}
    Foo(bool value) : result(value ? 1 : 0) {}
    explicit Foo(int value) : result(value) {}
    Foo operator+(bool value) const
    {
        std::cout << "adding " << value << std::endl;
        return Foo((result << 1) | (value ? 1 : 0));
    }
    int get_result() const { return result; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo x;
    x = Foo(true) + false + true;
    std::cout << x.get_result() << std::endl;
}
```

Play around with it [here](http://ideone.com/KuvgVK)